# Jenkins can't copy files to windows remote host

Tags: build, continuous-integration, command, jenkins, sudo

I have a Jenkins server on OS X 10.7, which polls a subversion server, builds the code and packages the app. The last step that I need to complete is deploying the app on a remote host, which is a windows share. Note that my domain account has write access to the target folder and the volume is mounted. I've tried using a shell script build step:

```
sudo cp "path/to/app" "/Volumes/path/to/target"
```

However i get a "no tty" response. I was able to run this command succesfully in Terminal, but not as a build step in Jenkins.

Does this have something to do with the user being used when starting up Jenkins? As a side note, the default user.name is jenkins and my JENKINS_HOME resides in /Users/Shared/Jenkins. I would appreciate any help as to how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *immediate* problem seems to be that you are running Jenkins in the background and `sudo` wants to input a password. Run Jenkins in the foreground with `$ java -jar jenkins.war`.

However, this most probably won't solve your problem as you'll be asked to enter a password when the command runs - from the terminal you started Jenkins from (presumably it's not what you want). You need to find a way to copy your files without needing root permissions. In general, it it not a good idea to rely on administrative permissions in your builds (there are exceptions, but your case is not it).

Comment: @user1418647, was this answer helpful?